# Letting a setter set a value of a property belonging to another class

Tags: php, immutability

Should a setter always be setting values of its direct properties and not of properties of associated objects? For example, I have something like below where the API client takes in an XML:

```
Class XML {
    private $value;

    // Setter for $value exists here
    ...
}

Class Client {
    private $xml; // XML
    public function __construct(XML $xml)
    {
        $this->xml = $xml;
        ...
    }    
}
```

I want the `$value` modified after `Client` is instantiated because, say, I want to change or add some options to the request. Should I use the setter in `XML` and re-instantiate the `Client` when modifying requests, or have a setter in `Client` directly so that I don't need to re-instantiate `Client`?

I'm typically prefer the former, but is there a reason why the latter approach would be preferred? I can't think of any except that it's easier to make quick changes.

Comment: Why do you need to re-instantiate the Client when properties change? Surely you can just do `$this->xml->setValue($newValue)`? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @revo what if someone was particular about XML being immutable (I added the setter in this example)? Would you still prefer the setter in Client?

Comment: @GraemeChapman same question^ for you too!

Comment: If an object / class is supposed to be immutable then thinking about second idea would be even wrong. You can create a modified copy however. But if it is just assumptions, don't think the other way. My previous comment was misleading, I removed it.

Comment: @revo appreciate the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, if a class has public methods, they are meant to be accessed. So, no harm in using them, you might think.

However, ask yourself: Why does a class have getters/setters in the first place? Accessors are usually found on classes for data objects. The main purpose of such objects is to carry data, they usually don’t *do* anything – unlike, for instance, a service or a controller class.

Next question: What is a constructor for? A constructor is used to set up the internal state of an object, and it will require it’s *dependencies* as parameters. In the spirit of loose coupling, dependencies should not be mutable from other classes.

Looking at your code, I guess that you’re writing some sort of XML-based client application and you want the `Client` class to depend on an instance of the `XML` class.

Modifying the internal state of the `XML` object from `Client` is a **bad idea**. Other classes depending on that instance will not know about the modification and will possibly get unexpected results.

There are several ways to solve this, depending on the actual task to perform:

1) If you need to set the value only for the context of a single method call of `XML`, modify the method to take `$value` as a parameter. But do not set it as an object member inside `XML`!

```
class XML
{
    public function doSomething($value)
    {
        …

        // do whatever you need with $value, 
        // but do *not* do something like $this->value = $value
    }
}
```

2) If the interaction with `$value` needs to be consistent across several operations, you should extract these operations from `XML` into an own worker or data object class. `XML` should then have a factory method to create an instance of this helper class. Then either `XML` or `Client` might have methods to use the worker:

```
class XML
{
    public function createWorker($value)
    {
        return new XmlWorker($value, $this);

        // XmlWorker might even contain a reference to the XML instance, e.g.
        return new XmlWorker($value, $this);
    }

    public function doSomethingWithWorker(XmlWorker $worker)
    {
        $value = $worker->getValue();
        $worker->doWork();
    }
}

class Client
{
    private function doSomething()
    {
        $worker = $this->xml->createWorker($value);
        $worker->doWork();
    }
}
```

I would recommend to read up on *Design Patterns*; in this context especially about Loose Coupling & Separation of Concerns, Factory methods and Depedency Injection.

Comment: You make some great points, and you guessed right. Don't need a worker just yet, but I settled on a paradigm where an immutable `XML` can be replaced entirely for `Client`. DI of course for all dependencies (except for `XML`, for now at least), and factory to make a `Client`. You read my mind.

Comment: Glad I could help you. :)